# How to quickly tell the n-order pole of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

I am following the Coursera course on Introduction to Complex Analysis and I am stuck at the following problem:

Evaluate the following using the residue theorem: $\int_{|z|=2}\frac{e^z}{(z-1)}dz$

I have successfully evaluated the problem using the following approach:

$\int_{|z|=2}\frac{e^z}{(z-1)}dz = \int_{|z|=2}e\frac{e^{(z-1)}}{(z-1)}dz$

$e\frac{e^{(z-1)}}{(z-1)}= e(\frac{1}{z-1}+1+\frac{z-1}{2}+...)$ by Taylor Expansion of $e$

Therefore the $a_{-1}$ is $e$. From there, we can evaluate that the answer is $2\pi i e$ using the residue theorem.

However, the answer given has a much shorter method which involves observing that $\frac{e^z}{(z-1)}$ has a simple pole. I am wondering how do you tell that this function has a simple pole without doing Laurent expansion.

Your help is appreciated!

Comment: $1$ is a simple root of the denominator and since around $z=1$ $e^z$ is holomorphic and $e^1 \neq 0$ we conclude that $z=1$ is a simple pole.

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis Thank you for your answer. To put it crudely, can I say that if the numerator of the function is analytic at the pole and doesn't equal to 0, then all I have to do is look at the power to which the denominator is raised to to infer the order of the pole?

Comment: Yes. The same also extends to non-polynomial functions. For example the function $f(z) = \frac{1}{1-\cos(z)}$ has a root of multiplicity $2$ at $z=2k\pi$ and the numerator is non-zero so it has poles of order $2$ at $z=2k\pi$. More generally, if the denominator has a root of multiplicity $m$ and the numerator a root of multiplicity $n < m$ at $z=z_0$ then the function has a pole of order $m-n$ at $z=z_0$.

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis that is extremely helpful, thank you so much!